# How to cause QComboBox pull-down menu to stay open

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to know how to make `QComboBox` pull-down menu to stay open.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Combo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Combo, self).__init__()
        self.addItems(['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5'])
        self.show()

tree=Combo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `QComboBox`'s pull-down menu stay open override its built-in `hidePopup()` method.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Combo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Combo, self).__init__()
        self.addItems(['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5'])
        self.show()

    def hidePopup (self):
        pass

inst=Combo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```